# How to get TypeScript to infer type from the function it's being passed to?

Tags: typescript

Given this code:

```
export type Resolvable<TValue = unknown, TArgs extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> = []> = TValue | ((...args: TArgs) => TValue)

export function fpShallowMerge<T>(...objects: Array<{
    [K in keyof T]?: Resolvable<T[K], [T[K], K]>;
}>): (obj: T) => T & {} {
    return {} as any
}

type State = {
    scale: number
    xOffset: number
    yOffset: number
}
let state: State = {
    scale: 0,
    xOffset: 0,
    yOffset: 0,
}
const setState = (fn: (prev: State) => State) => {
    state = fn(state)
}

setState(fpShallowMerge<State>({xOffset: 2, yOffset: 3}))  // works
setState(fpShallowMerge({xOffset: 2, yOffset: 3}))  // won't infer state
```

[TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBDAnmYcBKwDOEA2A3AQwCMdgAeAFQDUCcBXVAXjjoDsBrViAd1YBo4FAIJQA5pjigYwVgBMJGArIisciEVAKIybTj1YA+OMwDaAXSPNqtBnAA+cABSOAdG4JjMALkEjxASmMja3pgfwBYACgo0EhYOAAzNgBjGABLFUSwAGUAC1ocHgBZYDFyCgNXNwgiACtgVO84DS0yAG8ouC64EwBpODTWOHZgRAgEwTMAfh8MbHxiUko+swETChWBXosAbiiAXwN-H0ca2p8KQMZguAAyODb9h87uqGAYOighx7gCCQJWIgDlEokgUHBsjACNJjM9It04JhkrRgD5WHQALZEUovLogADyCQSmHeaMx2KguLgiEJxNJcHRWJxkX2UVI8EwUOkPkh0KYcIRSJRPgADHwqQSiSSYKLxfDujSpfSxcDIskVJzEe9eTDmI4EqwTmA3ngeVywkEIearkYOvKupy+bCDY5HdIIiyQZFpTrgPqcvkcIVuCUymRfZU2pK6TK4AAmASKmM+ADM+38gTgAHos3BuNB2Jgoj7zf68gViqVRH6o7TpT4E9S6-S0xmujm8yoAOTwQYJUqI81AA)

How can I change the type definition of `fpShallowMerge` so that TS is able to infer `T` as `State` for that last line of code?

Basically it should match `(obj: T) => T & {}` against `(prev: State) => State` and infer that `T` is a `State`.

---

The full implementation:

```
export function fpShallowMerge<T>(...objects: Array<{
    [K in keyof T]?: Resolvable<T[K], [T[K], K]>;
}>): (obj: T) => T & {} {
    return (obj: T) => {
        objects = objects.filter(o => o != null)
        if(!objects.length) {
            return obj
        }
        const ret = Object.assign(Object.create(null), obj)
        for(const o of objects) {
            for(const k of Object.keys(o!) as (keyof T)[]) {
                ret[k] = resolveValue(o![k], ret[k], k)
            }
        }
        return ret
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the problem seems `{xOffset: 2, yOffset: 3}` is not matching `State` s signature. `scale` is a required property for the State and you are not providing it. If you make it optional it will work.

Comment: Maybe it doesn't infer `T` as `State` because the object passed to the `fpShallowMerge` doesn't have `scale`?  It tries to match `{ xOffst: 2, yOffset: 3 }` to object of type `State` where the `scale` is not optional.

Comment: @Eldar It *is* optional, the argument type of `fpShallowMerge` is `[K in keyof T]?`. That's why the example with `<State>` works

Comment: @LevPleshkov Right, it appears to be matching on the argument to `fpShallowMerge` which makes enough sense, but I want to infer from `setState` instead. `setState` *only* takes in a `State` function. The autocomplete works that way: https://mpen.xyz/share/2023/02/phpstorm64_2023-02-13_00-05-48.png It even shows it as optional, as `scale?`

Comment: I think, the first call works because you have an explicit typecast there. `[K in keyof T]?` transforms your type into `Optional<State>` but the return type has the explicit type of `State`. If your method was not a dummy one that just returns any you would have some type compatibility issues in your function too. Removing `?` would make your function work precise

Comment: @Eldar I don't think there is an issue with the implementation (added to Q). It returns a function which necessarily takes in the full object and then merges in all the partial objects. The result can only be a full object. It's the same as `Object.assign({foo:1,bar:2},{bar:3})` the 2nd arg is partial but the return value necessarily still has `foo`.

Comment: `Object.assign(Object.create(null), obj)` this will return type of `any` so your function is still doing an assertion in the end.